# ajax is overwriting XHR object with multiple calls - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function *someFunction()* that sends an ajax requets via jQuery.

If the user gets click happy, the request seems to get overwritten... and I cant figure out why.

```
var request = $.ajax(customObject);
request.done(doneFunction);
request.fail(failFunction);
```

The XHR object being passed to *doneFunction()* & *failFunction()* is being overwritten each time the user fires the function.

This is an issue because the *doneFunction()* & *failFunction()* use delayed animation with call backs to change the html (derived from the XHR object) when the animation completes.

**Any thoughts/suggestions?**

- note I am using local var's not global var's... already thought of that...

Comment: how about delaying ajax? so if user clicks too often, it will still be delayed?...

Comment: No, I want to have the request be asynchronous...

Comment: Probably you have some closure variables in the wrong scope, which get overwritten by subsequent calls and are accessed from all callbacks. Please share the full code of your function, and maybe an example of how you call it so that it reproduces the mistake.

Comment: what do you mean by closure variables?

Comment: Problem solved thanks to Bergi. Stupid issue that was overlooked, doneFunction() was setting variables in the global scope. Thanks Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable to check whether a request has already been sent, and prevent sending another until that is complete. Something like this:

```
var requestSent = false;

function someFunction() {
    if (!requestSent) {
        requestSent = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: [url],
            type: [type],
            data: [data],
            success: function (xhr) {
                doneFunction(xhr);
                requestSent = false;
            },
            failure: function (xhr) {
                failFunction(xhr);
                requestSent = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It still is asynchronous in this solution?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to hide or disable the button, until the ajax call returns.  In your `someFunction()` you can disable the button, and show a "loading" spinner image, then in the `success` and `failure` callbacks, enable the button, and remove the "loading" spinner.

If you want to allow multiple requests, you'll need to implement a queue, and make the AJAX calls serially.  Basically, create an object to hold your queue of AJAX functions.  When one request returns, then call the next.  Here are a few examples:

- [small gist using jQuery's queue function](https://gist.github.com/gnarf/1039247)
- [a jQuery plugin from Alex MacCaw](https://gist.github.com/maccman/5790509)

Comment: There are multiple buttons... I want to be able to send multiple requests asynchronously...